# Langchain JSONLoader Error: OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long:

Tags: python, json, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

Help me to solve this error, i need the json data to be stored in chromadb, it's not loading into loader here i'm using Langchain JSON

```
import yfinance as yf

import json
from langchain import OpenAI
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings  
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.document_loaders import JSONLoader


stock_symbol = 'MSFT'  
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-08-15'

ticker = yf.Ticker(stock_symbol)
historical_data = ticker.history(start=start_date, end=end_date)

historical_data_json = historical_data.to_json(orient='index') 

embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
jq_schema = '.[] | {date: .key, open: .value."1. open", high: .value."2. high", low: .value."3. low", close: .value."4. close"}'

loader = JSONLoader(historical_data_json,jq_schema,text_content = False,json_lines=True)

# documents = loader.load()
# db = Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
loader.load()

OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '/Users/.....
```

Comment: The first argument to JSONLoader needs to be a filename and **not** a JSON structure (which is what historical_data_json is)